# How to solve " The system cannot find the path specified" error cygwin64/bin/snaphu?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, snap

[image]

I was trying to open the snaphu.conf file using python

```
process=subprocess.Popen(snaphu_args, cwd=str(temp_path),shell=True)
```

But error saying The system cannot find the file specified appears in the above line.
Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: Have you `snaphu` installed in your machine? Doesn't look like.

Comment: Yes it is installed. There's no issue in accessing snaphu directly through cygwin . But the error comes when i try to go to its path using my python code.

Comment: Looks like you are running a command shell. `bash -c ` does not set up the usual cygwin paths, so the shared libraries referenced by `snaphu.exe` cannot be found. I always run a mintty terminal with the bash shell when I am using cygwin apps. Considering adding the `-l` option to the bash command.